# How to access parent object properties?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it's possible from an object to access the properties of its parent, here is an explicite example, let's say we have an array of `People` objects in a `Group` object.

In this `Group` object, every `People` have the same address, so it will be nice to declare it in the `Group` and not in each `People` objects, but how to access it without parsing the collection?

```
function Group() {
  this.address = 'EveryWhere';
  this.Collection = [];
} 

function People(data) {
  this.name = data.name;

  this.getAddress = function() {
    return this.address; //how to access it (declared in the Group object)?
  }
}

var Serie = new Group();
var John = new People();
Serie.Collection.push(John);
console.log(John.getAddress());
```

Comment: Pass parent reference `new People( data , Serie )` .. and in `function People( data , serieRef) { this.parent = SerieRef`

Comment: A couple of style points: 1. By convention, initial capitals are used in JavaScript for constructor functions, so `function Group()` is good, but `this.Collection = [];`, `var Serie` and `var John` are odd because they're not constructor functions. 2. `Person` might be a better choice than `People` for that constructor function, as it looks like you use it to create one person, not some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic inheritance by assigning a new `Group` object to the `People.prototype`

```
function Group() {
  this.address = 'EveryWhere';
  this.Collection = [];
} 


function People(data) {
  this.name = data.name;

  this.getAddress = function() {
    return this.address; //how to access it (declared in the Group object)?
  }
};

People.prototype = new Group();

var Serie = new Group();
var John = new People({name:"John"});
console.log(John.getAddress());
```

Comment: Is this a good idea? Setting up a prototype inheritance sort of implies that (the some what odd named) people object also is a group - that it will have it's own Collection array and everything. This doesn't seem to be what the original poster wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Same as in many languages: pass the parent into the constructor of the child so you can hold a reference to it.

```
function People(data, parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.getAddress = function() {
        return this.parent.address;
    }
}
```

To make it safer, you can add a method on the parent to add children:

```
function Group() {
    // ... other code ...
    function addPeople(data) {
        this.collection.push(new People(data, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates a circular dependency.

Comment: @Adam: how so? `Group` doesn't depend on `People`, does it?

Comment: Well, yeah, Group will have a collection of People (I'd rename it to Person), and one People object will have a reference to one Group. But that's not really a problem (not like circular references in .NET). In fact, it's often used, and sometimes called a bidirectional relationship (specifically in ORM-circles, where it's often used for collections, i.e. in NHibernate).